# Show last post from multiple categories using wp_list_categories

Tags: loop, get-posts, categories

I have the following code that lists out the children categories on a separate page when you click on its parent category. The  code renders a list like so:

Home › Archive for IQ Issue 7

- Journal
- news
- world view

However I would like to retrieve the latest post from each of these categories and print underneath the category name. How could I achieve this within the loop below? I have tried several foreach loops but none seem to print the correct info. Thanks in advance.

category.php

```
<?php $this_category = get_queried_object();

// if parent is 0, category is top level
if( 0 == $this_category->parent ) :

    // top level category,
    // show child categories of this issue
    $args = array(
        'child_of' => $this_category->term_id,
        'title_li' => '',
        'hide_empty' => 0
    ); ?>

    <!-- output a list of child cats for this issue
    see also get_categories or get_terms if you wish to use your own markup-->


    <?php wp_list_categories($args); ?>





<?php else :

    // child category,
    // show articles in this subcategory, etc.
    echo 'child category';

endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all children categories using `get_terms()`. Loop through each term and run a new query using `tax_query`.

Example:

```
<?php if ( get_queried_object()->parent == 0 ) :  // parent cat ?>
    <h2>Showing all children</h2>
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'parent' => get_queried_object()->term_id
        );
        $terms = get_terms( 'category', $args );

        if ( $terms ) echo '<ul>';
        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
            $the_post = new WP_Query(array(
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                        'field' => 'id',
                        'terms' => $term->term_id
                    )
                )
            ));
        ?>
            <?php while ( $the_post->have_posts() ) : $the_post->the_post(); ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term, 'category'); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a> (Last article: <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>)</li>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <?php
        } //endforeach
        if ( $terms ) echo '</ul>';
    ?>

<?php else: // child ?>
    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thats brilliant thank you! When i can upvote i will make sure i do.